# Excel formula to return value based on a condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two sheets in my workbook. Sheet1 contains BRoll with Regd, and the other sheet2 contains Name with Regd. I want to copy Broll to sheet2. But I can't just copy and paste the Broll to sheet2 because the order is not the same. I tried the following formula. But it is not working

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B3:B15,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!B3:B15,0),1)
```

Please look at the image below. I put the data in both sheets here for convenience.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq677.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

*To copy `Broll number` into `Sheet 2`, you need combination of `INDEX & MATCH`*

[image]

- Formula in `L42`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$G$42:$G$53,MATCH(K42,Sheet1!$H$42:$H$53,0)),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

*Adjust Sheet name & cell references in the formula as needed.*

*In above formula `Blank Space` can be replaced with any Text like `No Match`*